# Angular get image from Spring RestController and cache it

Tags: java, spring, typescript, angular, spring-boot

I have a Client-Server application using SpringBoot and Angular2.
I would like to load a image from the server by filename. This works fine.

I store the attribute *image:string* at the client and I place it in the template again.
You might pay attention to *return res.url;*; I do not use the actual ressource, which might be wrong.

My objective is that image is cached. To my understanding the web-browser can automatically cache the images. Correct?
But the caching does not work yet and maybe somebody could give me a hint what needs to be adjusted?
Is a different header required?

Server (SpringBoot)

```
public class ImageRestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getImage/{filename:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> getImage(@PathVariable String filename) {

        try {
            String path = Paths.get(ROOT, filename).toString();
            Resource loader = resourceLoader.getResource("file:" + path);
            return new ResponseEntity<Resource>(loader, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Resource>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
}
```

Client (Angular2)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-image',
  template: `
    <img src="{{image}}"/>
  `
})

export class MyComponent {

  image:string;
  constructor(private service:MyService) {}

  showImage(filename:string) {
    this.service.getImage(filename)
      .subscribe((file) => {
          this.image = file;
        });
      }
}

export class MyService() {
  getImage(filename:String):Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(imagesUrl + "getImage/" + filename)
      .map(this.extractUrl)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  extractUrl(res:Response):string {
    return res.url;
  }
}
```

Comment: You could try sending `HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED` to clients you already served once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this on the server side (and perhaps add an ETag or Last-Modified header if you can get that information):

```
return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .cacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(30, TimeUnit.DAYS))
            .body(loader);
```

See the [HTTP caching part of the reference documentation in Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-caching-etag-lastmodified).

If you're just serving resources and not applying any additional logic, then you'd better do the following:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/getImage/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/path/to/root/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(1, TimeUnit.DAYS).cachePublic());
    }

}
```

See [the other relevant part of the reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-caching-static-resources). You can also apply transformations and leverage cache busting ([see this section as well](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources)).